# Modeling the Diode forward Characteristic

Tags: diodes, bias, modeling

I want to know easiest way to remember the modeling methods.

What I have figured out, is that we only have to find out resistance of diode in case of small signal model, otherwise we will be provided with the diode resistance in any case. Is that right? If not, then what are the formulas for that? Or how to find them?

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling

Answer (score 1):

Small-signal diode resistance \$r_D \$= \$n \cdot V_T \over I_b\$, where n is the ideality factor, \$V_T\$ is the thermal voltage, and \$I_b\$ is the bias current.

Derivation can be found at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling#Resistance).

Comment: Yes. This is valid only for small signal model. No?

Comment: Yes, "resistance" implies Ohm's law, and that only makes sense for a linearized small signal model. Diodes are quite nonlinear for large signals, as I'm sure you realize.

Comment: And what about PWL model? I have seen diode resistance is mostly given in that (problems). Would nvt/Id be valid for that too? If not, why?

Comment: It will give you the slope of the curve at any one point.  I don't think piecewise linear curves are used much these days outside of homework problems.